# Remove shadow/borderline on corner radius iOS

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I have two UIViews overlapping, with corner radius. They have both the same color. I´m trying to find out, how to prevent the corner radius make a slightly darker "border stroke" Does anyone know how to prevent this?

```
var topHistoryLine : UIView
var bottomHistoryLine :UIView

    topHistoryLine.layer.clipsToBounds = topHistoryLine.bounds.width/2
    topHistoryLine.clipsToBounds = true
    bottomHistoryLine.layer.cornerRadius = bottomHistoryLine.bounds.width/2
    bottomHistoryLine.clipsToBounds = true
    topHistoryLine.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.0
    bottomHistoryLine.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.0
```

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EzcQB.png)

Comment: add your code. The image is not clear at all.

Comment: Code added ;). The image is zoomed a lot to make the darker line visible. It´s a very small detail, almost impossible to see.

Answer (score 0):

```
View.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.0
View.layer.shadowRadius = 0.0
View.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.clear
```

Comment: It seams like its not a shadow preference, but the view itself, adjusting color, to make the curve look better.